# Serializing array and objects in Jquery, and deserializing in PHP after Ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a bunch of objects which I would like to post with Ajax. I am using `$.param` to serialize both the array and its objects prior to posting them to Ajax. When I debug the JS, it seems the serialization works fine, `myArray` and its contents don't look strange. But when I request the posted value in php, I just get a string of commas, something like `",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"`.

How should I be serializing and deserializing these objects and array?

```
var array= [];

$('.myselector').each(function() {
  var object = [];

  object ['x'] = a;
  object ['y'] = b; 
  object ['z'] = c; 

  $.param(object);
  array.push(object);
});

$.param(array);

// ...post object with ajax
```

Comment: why don't you json this with JSON.stringify then use json_decode() in php?

Comment: when I try this, my php receives a list string that looks like "["[]","[]","[]"....  Looking at the JS debugger, this makes since, because `JSON.stringify(object)` returns `"[]"`. So how do I serialize the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an object not an array, JSON.stringfy can not convert arrays with "non-numerical" keys. I modified your code to this...

```
$('.myselector').each(function() {
  var object = {};

  object ['x'] = a;
  object ['y'] = b; 
  object ['z'] = c; 

  var json = JSON.stringify(object);
});

// post json to your server
```